# Django Rest Framework with Firebase Firestore - API endpoint returns NoneType due to initialize_app runs more than once

Tags: django, firebase, api, google-cloud-firestore, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build a read-only API that fetches its data from Firebase, Firestore. I'm having an issue when I request any endpoint in my API, multiple times, I get an error.

I won't include Django related files and classes. So, here are the code pieces you need to know.

**firebase_initilizer.py**

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

if not firebase_admin._apps:
    cred = credentials.Certificate('./FILE_PATH.json') 
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()
collection_ref = db.collection(u"collection-name")
docs = collection_ref.stream()
```

**views.py** [A simplified version of what I use in one of my API endpoints]

```
class Contact(APIView):
    """
    Returns the user's contact details.
    """
    def get(self, request, uid, format="json"):
        for doc in docs:
            if uid == doc.id:
                return Response(data=doc.to_dict()["contact"], status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Again, the issue is that I get an error saying "NoneType" whenever I request any endpoint more than once. At this point, I can run my API only once.

**The error:**

```
AssertionError at /api/v1/contact/
Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
"GET /api/v1/contact/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78864
```

From what I know, I need to initialize Firebase only once. Then, I only need to request whatever I want by using the variable I assigned the Firebase reference. However, I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by inserting my firebase initializer code piece into manage.py. Plus, it also works in settings.py.

For example, the manage.py file can be rearranged as follows:

```
import os, sys
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'api.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
        if not firebase_admin._apps:
            cred = credentials.Certificate('./FILE_PATH.json') 
            firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

or you can simply add the following lines to anywhere in settings.py:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials

if not firebase_admin._apps:
    cred = credentials.Certificate('./FILE_PATH.json') 
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

I hope this answer helps others.